# Exponential Search vs Binary Search

Tags: algorithm, search

Does a binary search beat an exponential search in any way, except in space complexity?

Comment: Well, what are your metrics? Personally I think "binary search" is easier to spell, which is great.

Comment: time complexity wise, exponential search beats binary search in many cases. lets keep time complexity to be the metric.

Comment: Time *complexity* is the same for both (because big-O ignores constants). But given an array whose size is known in advance, exponential search is faster for some values (those near the beginning of the array), and binary search is faster for others. I expect that binary search is faster on average, but I don't have any numbers to back that up.

Answer (score 16):

Both these algorithms search for a value in an ordered list of elements, but they address different issues. Exponential search is explicitly designed for unbounded lists whereas binary search deals with bounded lists.

The idea behind exponential search is very simple: Search for a bound, and *then* perform a binary search.

## Example

Let's take an example. `A = [1, 3, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15, 19, 21, 22, 23, 29, 31, 37]`. This list can be seen as a binary tree (although there is no need to build the tree):

```
             15
        ____/  \____
       /            \
    __8__           _23__
   /     \         /     \
  3      11       21     31
 / \    /  \     /  \   /  \
1   7  10   12  19  22 29  37
```

### Binary search

A binary search for `e = 27` (for example) will undergo the following steps

b0) Let `T, R` be the tree and its root respectively

```
                 15 (R)
            ____/  \____
           /            \
        __8__           _23__
       /     \         /     \
      3      11       21     31
     / \    /  \     /  \   /  \
    1   7  10   12  19  22 29  37
```

b1) Compare `e` to `R`: `e > 15`. Let `T, R` be `T` right subtree and its root respectively

```
                 15
            ____/  \____
           /            \
        __8__           _23_(R)
       /     \         /     \
      3      11       21     31
     / \    /  \     /  \   /  \
    1   7  10   12  19  22 29  37
```

b2) Compare `e` to `R`: `e > 23`. Let `T, R` be `T` right subtree and its root respectively

```
                 15
            ____/  \____
           /            \
        __8__           _23__
       /     \         /     \
      3      11       21     31 (R)
     / \    /  \     /  \   /  \
    1   7  10   12  19  22 29  37
```

b3) Compare `e` to `R`: `e < 31`. Let `T, R` be `T` left subtree and its root respectively

```
                 15
            ____/  \____
           /            \
        __8__           _23__
       /     \         /     \
      3      11       21     31___
     / \    /  \     /  \   /     \
    1   7  10   12  19  22 29 (R)  37
```

b4) Compare `e` to `R`: `e <> 29`: the element is not in the list, since `T` has no subtree.

### Exponential search

An exponential search for `e = 27` (for example) will undergo the following steps

Let `T, R` be the leftmost subtree (ie the leaf `1`) and its root (`1`) respectively

```
                 15
            ____/  \____
           /            \
        __8__           _23__
       /     \         /     \
      3      11       21     31
     / \    /  \     /  \   /  \
(R) 1   7  10   12  19  22 29  37
```

e1) Compare `e` to `R`: `e > 1`. Let `R` be the parent of `R` and `T` be the tree having `R` as root

```
                 15
            ____/  \____
           /            \
        __8__           _23__
       /     \         /     \
  (R) 3      11       21     31 (R)
     / \    /  \     /  \   /  \
    1   7  10   12  19  22 29  37
```

e2) Compare `e` to `R`: `e > 3`. Let `R` be the parent of `R` and `T` be the tree having `R` as root:

```
                 15
            ____/  \____
           /            \
      (R)_8__           _23__
       /     \         /     \
      3      11       21     31 (R)
     / \    /  \     /  \   /  \
    1   7  10   12  19  22 29  37
```

e3) Compare `e` to `R`: `e > 8`. Let `R` be the parent of `R` and `T` be the tree having `R` as root:

```
             (R) 15
            ____/  \____
           /            \
        __8__           _23__
       /     \         /     \
      3      11       21     31 (R)
     / \    /  \     /  \   /  \
    1   7  10   12  19  22 29  37
```

e4) Compare `e` to `R`: `e > 15`. `R` has no parent. Let `T` be the right subtree of `T` and `R` be its root:

```
                 15
            ____/  \____
           /            \
        __8__           _23_(R)
       /     \         /     \
      3      11       21     31
     / \    /  \     /  \   /  \
    1   7  10   12  19  22 29  37
```

e5..7) See steps b2..4)

## Time complexity

**For the sake of demonstration, let `N = 2^n` be the size of `A`** and let indices start from `1`. If `N` is not a power of two, the results are almost the same.

Let `0 <= i <= n` be the minimum so that `A[2^(i-1)] < e <= A[2^i]` (let `A[2^-1] = -inf`). Note that this kind of interval may not be unique if you have duplicate values, hence the "minimum".

### Exponential search

You need `i + 1` iterations to find `i`. (In the example, you are jumping from child to parent repeatedly until you find a parent greater than `e` or there is no more parent)

Then you use a binary search on the selected interval. The size of this interval is `2^i - 2^(i-1) = 2^(i-1)`.

The cost of a binary search in an array of size `2^k` is variable: you might find the value in the first iteration, or after `k` iterations (There are sophisticated analysis depending on the distribution of the elements, but basically, it's between `1` and `k` iterations and you can't know it in advance)

Let `j_i, 1 <= j_i <= i - 1` be the number of iterations needed for the binary search in our case (The size of this interval is `2^(i-1)`).

### Binary search

Let `i` be the minimum so that `A[2^(i-1)] < e <= A[2^i]`. Because of the assumption that `N = 2^n`, the binary search will meet this interval:

We start with the root `A[2^(n-1)]`. If `e > A[2^(n-1)]`, `i = n` because `R = A[2^(n-1)] < e < A[2^n]`. Else, we have `e <= A[2^(n-1)]`. If `e > A[2^(n-2)]`, then `i = n-1`, else we continue until we find `i`.

You need `n - i + 1` steps to find `i` using a binary search:

- if `i = n`, you know it at the first iteration (`e > R`) else, you select the left subtree
- if `i = n-1`, you need two iterations
- and so on: if `i = 0`, you'll need `n` iterations.

Then you'll need `j_i` iterations as shown above to complete the search.

### Comparison

As you see, the `j_i` iterations are common to both algorithms. The question is: Is `i + 1 < n - i + 1`? i.e. Is `i < n - i` or `2i < n`? If yes, the exponential search will be faster than the binary search. If no, the binary search will be faster than the exponential search (or equally fast)

Let's get some distance: `2i < n` is equivalent to `(2^i)^2 < 2^n` or `2^i < sqrt(2^n)`. While `2^i < sqrt(N)`, the exponential search is faster. As soon as `2^i > sqrt(N)`, the binary search is faster. Remember that the index of `e` is lower or equal than `2^i` because `e <= A[2^i]`.

In simple words, if you have `N` elements and if `e` is in the first`sqrt(N)` elements, then exponential search will be faster, else binary search will be faster.

It depends on the distribution, but `N - sqrt(N) > sqrt(N)` if `N > 4`, and thus *the binary search is likely to be faster than the exponential search unless you know that the element will be among the first ones or the list is ridiculously short*.

### If `2^n < N < 2^(n+1)`

I won't go into details, but this does not change the general conclusion.

If the value is beyond the last power of two, the cost of exponential to find the bound is already `n+2`, more than the binary search (less than or equal to `2^(n+1)`). Then you have a binary search to perform, maybe in a small interval, but binary search is already the winner.

Else you add the value `A[N]` to the list until you have `2^(n+1)` value. This won't change anything for exponential search, and this will slow down the binary search. But this slow binary search remains faster if `e` is not in the first`sqrt(2^(n+1))` values.

## Space complexity

That's an interesting question which I don't talk about, size of the pointer and things like that. If you are performing an exponential search and consuming elements as they arrive (imagine timestamps), you don't need to store the whole list at once. You just have to store one element (the first), then one element (the second), then two elements (the third and the fourth), then four elements, ... then `2^(i-1)` elements. If `i` is small, then you won't need to store a large list as in a regular binary search.

## Implementation

Implementation is really not a problem here. See the Wikipedia pages for information: [Binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Procedure) and [Exponential search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search#Algorithm).

## Applications and how to choose among the two

**Use the exponential search only when the sequence is unbounded or when you know the value is likely to be among the first ones.** Unbounded: I like the example of timestamps: they are strictly growing. You can imagine a server with stored timestamps. You can ask for `n`  timestamps and you are looking for a specific timestamp. Ask 1, then 2, then 4, then 8,... timestamps and perform the binary search when one timestamps exceeds the value you are looking for.

**In other cases, use the binary search.**

Remark: the idea behind the first part of the exponential search has some applications:

- Guess an integer number when the upper limit is unbounded: Try 1, 2, 4, 8, 16,... and narrow the guess when you exceed the number (this is exponential search);
- Find a bridge to cross a river by a foggy day: Make 100 steps left. If you didn't find the bridge, return to the initial point and make 200 steps right. If you still didn't find the bridge, return to the initial point and make 400 steps left. Repeat until you find the bridge (or swim);
- Comput a congestion window in the [TCP slow start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion_control#Slow_start): Double the quantity of data sent until there is a congestion. The TCP congestion algorithms are in general more careful and perform something similar to a linear search in the second part of the algorithm, because exceeding tries have a cost here.

Comment: You deserve my bounty